# How to use circuit breaker based on a method parameter?

Tags: java, circuit-breaker, resilience4j, java-failsafe

I have a http client that connects to the same api endpoint on different servers. Which server it connects to, depends on business logic.

Let's say the http client method is `connect(url)`. How can I make sure that the circuit breaker takes the url into account? If my http client sends requests to both `url_A` and `url_B` , and server A goes down, then I want that my http client can still send requests to server B.

Does Failsafe or Resilience4J support this out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all your CircuitBreakers will use the same configuration.
you can create a global config like below.

```
public CircuitBreakerConfig defaultConfig(){
    return CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
          .failureRateThreshold(50)
          .slowCallRateThreshold(50)
          .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
          .slowCallDurationThreshold(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
          .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(3)
          .minimumNumberOfCalls(10)
          .slidingWindowType(SlidingWindowType.TIME_BASED)
          .slidingWindowSize(5)
          .recordException(e -> INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
                         .equals(getResponse().getStatus()))
          .recordExceptions(IOException.class, TimeoutException.class)
          .ignoreExceptions(BusinessException.class, OtherBusinessException.class)
          .build();
}
```

once you have the config then create a CircuitBreakerRegistry bean with a custom global configuration

```
@Bean
public CircuitBreakerRegistry cbRegistry(){
      return CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(defaultConfig());
}
```

Now you can get or create a CircuitBreaker with the global configuration with your URL as name using the above created CircuitBreaker Registry

```
@Autowired
private CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry;

public boolean connect(url){
    CircuitBreaker cb = circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker(url);
    // use this cb to decorate your connection creation code.
    Decorators.ofSupplier(() -> {
        // code to make rest call
        return "";
    }).withCircuitBreaker(some).decorate().get();
}
```

Comment: Could you please provice the whole example ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow above code is enough to create a CB for a URL. can you please tell me what else do you need?